# C++ to draw cards troubleshooting

Tags: c++, random, counter

I am stuck with this program and cannot seem to figure out why it is crashing like it is. It complies fine, but when ran, and user input is collected it stops responding forcing the user to close.

All it is supposed to do is ask a user how many hands of 5 cards they would like to draw. Once entered the program is simply supposed to randomly pick that number of hands, and then close. Thanks in advance!!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Card    //defines a custom "structured" variable type
{
   int    kind;
   char   kindDisplay;
   string suit;
};

 bool havePair (Card hand[])
 {
  int count[13];
  int i,k;
  bool pair;

  for (i=0; i <=12; i++)
     count[i] = 0;

  for (i=1; i<= 5; i++)
     count[hand[i].kind]++;
  pair = false; 

  for (i=0; i <= 12;i++)
     if (count[i] > 1)
        pair = true;
  return pair;

 }

int main ()
{
   int numHands;
   int pairCount =0;
   bool    hasBeenDrawn[52];  // has given card been drawn already?
   int     suitDrawn;         // 0=clubs,1=diamonds,2=spades,3=hearts
   int     kindDrawn;              // index of kind from 0 to 12,
                              // representing 2,3,...9,10,J,Q,K,A
   Card hand[6];
   int     num;     // randomly generated card to pick (from 0 to 51).
   int     cardCount;   // counts how many cards have been drawn;
   int     i,j;
   unsigned int seed;  // seed for random number generator

   seed = time(0);      
   srand(seed);

   cout << "Enter # of hands to draw: ";
   cin >> numHands;
   cout << endl;
   for (j=1; j<= numHands; j++)
   {

      for (i=0; i < 52; i ++)
          hasBeenDrawn[i] = false;

      for (cardCount=1; cardCount <=5; cardCount++)  // draw 5 cards
      {
         do
         {
            num = rand()%52; // get random number between 0 & 51 inclusive
         } while (hasBeenDrawn[num] == true);

         hasBeenDrawn[num] = true;

         suitDrawn = num / 13; // quotient will be 0, 1, 2, or 3

         switch (suitDrawn)
         {
            case 0: hand[cardCount].suit = "  clubs   ";
               break;
            case 1: hand[cardCount].suit = "  diamonds";
               break;
            case 2: hand[cardCount].suit = "  spades  ";
               break;
            case 3: hand[cardCount].suit = "  hearts  ";
               break;
         }
         kindDrawn = num % 13;
         hand[cardCount].kind = kindDrawn;

         if      (kindDrawn == 12) hand[cardCount].kindDisplay = 'A';
         else if (kindDrawn == 11) hand[cardCount].kindDisplay = 'K';
         else if (kindDrawn == 10) hand[cardCount].kindDisplay = 'Q';
         else if (kindDrawn ==  9) hand[cardCount].kindDisplay = 'J';
         else if (kindDrawn ==  8) hand[cardCount].kindDisplay = 'T'; // a "ten"
         else
                              hand[cardCount].kindDisplay =  (char)(kindDrawn + 50);

        if (havePair(hand) == true)
           pairCount++;
        }

         //Note: ASCII character codes for '0','1',...,'9' are 48 through 57
      }  // end for loop (cardCount = 1 to 5) draw 5 cards
      cout << endl << endl;
      cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
      cout << "Experimental % of pairs: " << (double)numHands*100.0 << endl;
      cout << "Theoretical % of pairs: " << (2598960-1317888)/(double)(2598960)*100.0 << endl;  //approximate # of hands that don't have a pair
      cout << endl;
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Run in a debugger or add some prints to find out what is going on - if it "freezes" it sounds like it's getting stuck in a loop... p.s. arrays start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @John3136 Thanks for the reply! Where could I get a C++ debugger? I've never used one for the language. I tried to find one once but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What OS? gdb is the first one that springs to mind. If you don't have a debugger addings prints will show you which bits your code is reaching and which it isn;t.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8, 32 bit at the moment.

Comment: It isn't the OS that is important - it is the compiler.  Are you using Visual Studio or mingw?  If you are using visual studio then you just need to hit the play and pause buttons.  With mingw it will be gdb.  it doesn't freeze for me - it force closes.  The error is: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. in havePair (hand=0x22fdb0) at x.cpp on line 24: count[hand[i].kind]++;`  What happens if you enter less than 5 hands?  Then hand[i].kind won't have a value.

Comment: If u are using visual studio, debugger should be built in (not sure about the express editions...)

Comment: I'm using the Mingw compiler. So I need to use the gdb debugger?

Comment: Make sure the `Card hand[]` structure you are passing has a `sizeof >= 5`

Comment: @mr5 Even if I use a number > 5 it still will not work.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Does that mean there is an actual problem in my `havePair` function that i'm missing? Also, i'm getting the same error regardless if I enter a number greater or less than 5.

Comment: @TheWiz I forgot also to tell that the value of `hand[i].kind` should be less or equal to the size of `count[]` w/c is `13`.

Comment: @mr5 Thanks for the advice, but what exactly does that mean on my end? As far as correcting the program goes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hand` array is not fully initialized when you are calling the `havePair()` function.

You should call the `havePair()` function from out of the loop after hand array has been filled up.

EDIT: As suggested by John3136, this is a good time to start using a debugger. It will help you solve such errors in future as well.

Change your `havePair()` function to:

```
int numOfPairs (Card hand[])
 {
  int count[13];
  int i,k;
  int pair;

  for (i=0; i <=12; i++)
     count[i] = 0;

  for (i=1; i<= 5; i++)
     count[hand[i].kind]++;
  pair = 0; 

  for (i=0; i <= 12;i++)
     if (count[i] > 1)
        pair++;
  return pair;

 }
```

And this part:

```
       if (havePair(hand) == true)
       pairCount++;
    }

     //Note: ASCII character codes for '0','1',...,'9' are 48 through 57
  }  // end for loop (cardCount = 1 to 5) draw 5 cards
  cout << endl << endl;
```

to

```
     pairCount = numOfPairs( hand );
     //Note: ASCII character codes for '0','1',...,'9' are 48 through 57
  }  // end for loop (cardCount = 1 to 5) draw 5 cards

  cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: If I move it beneath `int main()` it is not declared in the scope. Then if I declare it I get "havePair cannot be used as a function. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I see what you did, and it makes sense. However, I am still getting the same error after I compile the program and input the number of hands it stops working.

Comment: @TheWiz There seems to be some problems in your braces indentation. See my update. I suggest you use a debugger or debug yourself using std::cout statements.